# Setting a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Hi I've got the following SQL procedure that I want to run, but I don't know how to set the variable @AgencyProfileID.

```
EXEC CreateAgencyPayPeriodsWeekly
@AgencyProfileID,
'2017-02-14',       -- Start date (date of first day of first period to be paid)
'2017-03-27',       -- End Date (date of last day of last period to be paid in this tax year)
'2017-02-28',       -- First payment date
14,                 -- Period length, either 7 or 14 days
0,                  -- Remove existing YTD details (always false)
0,                  -- Remove existing pay periods (always false)
0                   -- Create actual pay periods, set to 0 for Hypo
```

If the AgencyProfileID was 101 would I just place the following between the first and second line?

```
EXEC CreateAgencyPayPeriodsWeekly
set @AgencyProfileID = 101
@AgencyProfileID,
```

I'm new to SQL and don't want to break anything!

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/set-vs-select-assigning-variables.aspx

Comment: just google it.

Comment: if you're new to SQL, ask someone that knows what they are doing in your workplace, not on a public forum where we have little knowledge of the internals of your system.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tanner and thanks for the website L_Church that's really useful

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Answer (score 0):

you could either do

```
declare @AgencyProfileID int = 101

EXEC CreateAgencyPayPeriodsWeekly
@AgencyProfileID,
'2017-02-14',      
'2017-03-27',      
'2017-02-28',      
14,                
0,                 
0,                 
0
```

or just:

```
EXEC CreateAgencyPayPeriodsWeekly
101,
'2017-02-14',      
'2017-03-27',      
'2017-02-28',      
14,                
0,                 
0,                 
0
```